# Magento 2: Filter Product Collection by Multiple Categories (Magento 2.1)

Tags: magento2, collection, magento-2.1, filter, product-collection

I'm using **Magento 2.1.0** and I'm currently having difficulties in filtering product collection with multiple categories. I've used more than a couple of ways to make it work but it won't.

Assuming:

```
$catalog_ids = [618, 619, 620];
```

1. Returns NULL

   ```
   $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
   ```
2. Returns exception: *Invalid attribute name: category_id*

   ```
   $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
           'finset' => $catalog_ids
       ));
   ```
3. Returns *Syntax error or access violation*

   ```
   $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
       ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids', array(
           'finset' => $catalog_ids
       ));
   ```

Any advice on how I could be able to have this work or have something link this work?

Comment: Try to check generated sql.
$productCollection->getSelectSql(true);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably used to the "every method returns `$this`" paradigm from Magento 1. **This is not the case anymore** (at least not always).

Specifically, `addCategoriesFilter()` does not return anything and that's why you get `null`.

Change the code to:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $catalog_ids));
```

Comment: To suggest that it is not the case anymore is probably stated too strongly. The function 'addCategoryFilter' (singular) in the same class does return $this; so adding the return value in 'addCategoriesFilter' has probably just escaped the attention of a developer.

Comment: yeah, that would make sense too

Answer (score 5):

Your first try is definitely the right way of doing it:

```
$values = [318, 619, 620];
$conditionType = "in";
$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter([$conditionType => $values]);
```

Now there's two things to ensure: `$productCollection` must be an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` for this to work (or from a class that extends it).

And obviously you need to have products in the `catalog_category_product` table that matches that condition, maybe that's not the case and that's why you get NULL.

Comment: Which is the better way using product collection or using service contracts? Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface

Comment: @MagePsycho if you have the choice always go for service contracts ;)